# how can i get ToLower to work in an expression?

Tags: linq, expression, tolower

I have the following line of code:

`protected Expression<Predicate<DuplicateCheck>> Name= x => x.Name == "smith";`

when I add a `.ToLower()`

`protected Expression<Predicate<DuplicateCheck>> Name= x => x.Name.ToLower() == "smith";`

to try to generalize the query I get the error

`System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a target.'`

Is this not available to use in this way?

Comment: How are you using `Name`? What is `Predicate<>`? Reflection is not involved in the definition of `Name` so the library or system you are using it with must be trying to parse the `ExpressionLambda` and doesn't handle complicated expressions. What library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Non-static method requires a
>   target.'

Normally it happens when the target is `null`, So you need to check it first like below.

```
x => x != null && x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower() == "smith"
```

Comment: this didn't work for me unfortunately... same error.

Comment: Did you add more condition `x != null` as I edited my question?

Comment: we could simplify it to `x => x?.Name?.ToLower() == "smith"`

Comment: Yes, If the OP is using `C# 6 features – Null-conditional`